# What are the main differences between latexmk and C-c C-a from Auctex?

Tags: latex, auctex, automation

I was wondering if anyone knows if `C-c C-a` in AucTeX is using behind the scenes latexmk or not? I've tried looking into the source files for both `C-c C-c` and `C-c C-a` but I couldn't find in any those traces of latexmk.

On a side note what best way to integrate latexmk in AucTeX workflow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`C-c C-a` uses AuCTeX's heuristics for deciding which list of commands to run.  The usual case is to use the function `TeX-command-default` which is defined in `tex-buf.el`.  So no, `latexmk` is not used.

You can make `latexmk` accessible from `C-c C-c` by customizing `TeX-command-list`.  One possibility is to a add an element of the form

```
INS DEL :
            Name: LaTeXmk
            Command: latexmk %s
            How: Value Menu TeX-run-TeX
                    Create a process for NAME using COMMAND to format FILE with TeX.
            Prompt: Toggle  off (nil)
            Modes: Value Menu All
            Menu elements:
            INS DEL Lisp expression: :help
            INS DEL Lisp expression: "Run latexmk."
            INS
```

which adds

```
 ("LaTeXmk" "latexmk %s" TeX-run-TeX nil t :help "Run latexmk.")
```

to `TeX-command-list`.  Once this is done, on typing `C-c C-c` you can choose `LaTeXmk` as the command to run.  Next time you type `C-c C-c` this will be offered as the default, so can be accepted with just `RET`.

Look at the other elements in `TeX-command-list` to get an idea of ways to pass further options to `latexmk` should you need them.

Comment: Did you actually want to write "`C-c C-a` uses AuCTeX's **own**..."?

Comment: Thanks, Andrew, neat explanation, the reason I was initially asking is because `C-c C-a` sometimes fails to properly compile if you've changed the .bib file by adding new entries, but latexmk breezes over that.

Comment: @KirkWalla This is worth a bug-report via `M-x TeX-submit-bug-report`. As far as I see, the last related error is [one with multiply defined labels in the document](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=24771). If you submit a bug-report add a minimal example for reconstruction of the problem to it! Thanks for making AucTeX better!

Answer (score 3):

Why not just add it directly to ~/.emacs?

```el
(with-eval-after-load 'tex
  (add-to-list
   'TeX-command-list
   '("LaTeXmk" "latexmk %s" TeX-run-TeX nil t :help "Run latexmk.")))
```